# Как hashmap по значению найти ключ

Tags: java

Имеется hashmap, как можно по  значению найти ключ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, ключей для одного и того же значения может быть множество.

Во-вторых, если у вас никаких других данных нет, вам ничего не остаётся
как просто итерировать по хэшу и смотреть, подходит вам этот ключ или нет.

```
public static void processMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if (pair.getValue() == '...') {
          System.out.println("Found: " + pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        }
        it.remove(); // дабы не было ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

В данном случае я прохожу по хэшу и как только значение равно `...`,
я вывожу его на стандартный поток вывода. Вы делаете в данном случае ваши действия с найденным значением.

Другой способ пройтись по хэшу:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

В JDK нет поддержки двунаправленных `Map` , поэтому только самому костылить что то вроде этого:

```
public K getKeytoValue (Map map ,V someValue){
 for(Entry entry: map.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getValue().equals(someValue)) return entry.getKey();
 }
return null;
}
```

где: `K` - тип объекта ключа , `V` - тип объекта значения , `someValue` - значение, для которого нужно найти ключ.

если одинаковых значений несколько , то будет возвращен ключ , естественно , только первого.